# Are patrons expected to tip at restaurants in Paraguay?

Tags: local-customs, tipping, paraguay, asuncion

So I finish my meal at a restaurant in Asunción, and I'm getting ready to pay when I notice at the top of my receipt it says, "propina no incluida" ("tip not included").

I thought tipping was not customary in Paraguay; is this an exception, or is there something fishy going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a page on [tipping and gratuities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_%28gratuity%29#Paraguay), and claims:

> Service charges are included with the bill, and tipping is uncommon

However, their link is broken and I suspect it might be wrong.  All other resources I can find online indicate that you should, and how much.

[About.com:](http://gosouthamerica.about.com/library/weekly/aa101200a.htm)

> 10% in restaurants and taxis. $.50 - .75 per bag to porters

[Ideamarketers.com](http://www.ideamarketers.com/?articleid=935352):

> In Paraguay, restaurants that do not automatically add gratuity (it
>   will say if they do at the bottom of your menu) then a tip of 10
>   percent is enough. I found that my servers delighted in the other-
>   than- monetary- tips I gave them. Paperback books, picture books
>   (postcards) and compliments to their managers were high on their list.
>   In taxis no tips are necessary. The standard of $.50-$.75 per bag to
>   handlers was the norm.

[Southtravels.com](http://www.southtravels.com/america/paraguay/traveltips.html#tipping):

> 10% should be left for the waiters. Small change should be given to
>   porters and taxi drivers.

So perhaps the culture has changed, but all signs are indicating that yes, you should tip, and especially if the restaurant indicates as such.